# How to multiply [Batch_Size, A, B] tensor by [Batch_Size, B] tensor to yield [Batch_Size, A] tensor?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Question as in title — how do I multiply two tensors of those shapes to yield a tensor of that shape?

```
[Batch_Size, A, B] x [Batch_Size, B] = [Batch_Size, A]
```

`tf.matmul()` requires the tensors be of the same rank.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tensor1 = tf.zeros([10, 64, 64])
tensor2 = tf.zeros([10, 64])

# dot = tf.matmul(tensor1, tensor2)  # NOT THIS
dot = tf.einsum('ijk,ik->ij', tensor1, tensor2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(dot).shape)
```